# how woocommerce swatch color name when hovered or selected

Tags: plugins, javascript, hacks

I have the woocommerce plugin and the woocommerce swatches and photos extension that shows swatches instead of variations as a drop down.

When hovering over the swatches and when a swatch is selected, I would like to be able to see the name of the color above the color table.

[enter link description here](http://www.thetrimmingcompany.com/featured-products/veiling-plain-br001)

like the link above

please and thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I’ve got it to show the variation name in a separate div on “hover”, but not yet on “click” as there seems to be a conflict somewhere with WooCommerce.

First of all, place an empty div somewhere on the single product page in your child theme, I'm using `/single-product/meta.php`.

My div looks like this: `<div id="colour-name"></div>`.

Then you can use the following javascript to show the variation name:

```
$j=jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() { 
  $j(".swatch-anchor").hover(function() {
  var newTitle = $j(this).attr("title");
  $j("#colour-name").html(newTitle);
  },
  function() {
  var swapTitle = $j("#colour-name").html();
  $j(this).attr("title",swapTitle);
  $j("#colour-name").html("");
});});
```